# Can not convert from Action<T> to Action<Event> even through T is restricted to Extend from Event?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the code posted below and I can not figure out why this is not possible. I am getting a compiler error: cannot convert from System.Action to System.Action.

And what would be the correct way to implement something like this?

I am coming from a Java background and I am trying to accomplish something I could normally do using a wildcard generic. However I am not understanding why I am getting this error when T is restricted to be something that extends Event.

I omitted the code making sure the list actually exits.

```
    public class EventBus : ScriptableObject {

        public Event[] events;

        private Dictionary<Type, List<Action<Event>>> listeners = new Dictionary<Type, List<Action<Event>>>();

        public void Register<T>(Action<T> function) where T : Event {
            listeners[typeof(T)].Add(function);
        }

    }

    // The event class
    public abstract class Event : ScriptableObject {
        public abstract void Raise();
    }
```

**Update**

Basicaly I was trying to do something like this:

```
eventBus.register<CutomEvent>(MyFunction);
```

where

```
public void MyFunction(CustomEvent event);
```

This way I can specify what event I want to listen to with the generic parameter. The dictionary just holds a list of every function that wants to listen to a specific Type of event

**Update:**
Here is what I have in Java

```
public class EventBus {

    public Map<Class<?>, List<SomeInterface<?>>> listeners = new HashMap<>();

    public<T extends Event> void register(SomeInterface<T> func, Class<T> clazz) {
        listeners.get(clazz).add(func);
    }

    public interface SomeInterface<T extends Event> {
        void process(T event);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new EventBus().register(event -> {
            // Do something with my event
            event.someFunc();
        }, MyEvent.class);

    }

    private static class MyEvent extends Event {
        public void someFunc(){}
    }

}
```

Comment: I also tried making Event a concrete class that doesn't extend anything.

Comment: Just because `T` inherits from `Event` it **does not mean** that `Action<T>` inherits from `Action<Event>` - it **does not**.

Comment: err.. That's confusing... I am restricting T in that scope to T : Event. So does that not mean that Action<T> has to be Action<T : Event> so no matter what T is it will extend from Event, which means it can be cast to Action<Event> ?!

Comment: @EvgenyVasilyev - `Action<T>` cannot derive from `Action<Event>` no matter what constraint you put on `T`.

Comment: @EvgenyVasilyev - Let's say you have a `List<Apple>` and that `Apple` inherits from `Fruit`, then, if you could cast a `List<Apple>` to `List<Fruit>` you would be able to do `list.Add(new Banana())` (as `Banana` inherits from `Fruit`), but that just doesn't make sense that the compiler would let you write code that code because a `List<Apple>` cannot add an instance of `Banana`. That's why `Action<T>` cannot be cast to `Action<Event>`.

Comment: @mjwills - Sorry for the confusion. I'm making `List<Apple>` analogous to `Action<T>`, not to `List<Action<T>>`.

Comment: @mjwills - Yes, I can see that too. I just felt that most developers can understand that they can't add a `Banana` to a `List<Apple>` so therefore the compiler disallows casting of a `List<Apple>` to a `List<Fruit>`. Thus making the error of casting an `Action<T>` to a `Action<Event>` a little easier to understand.

Comment: I think understand your example but fail to see how it maps to this scenario. In this case I am making a List<Fruit> and I am expecting that anything I pass in would extend from Fruit by adding the restriction. Fruit being the Event, and everything used as the parameter has to be an Event, so when i do listeners[index] I will be guaranteed to get back an Event.

Comment: @EvgenyVasilyev - You're not making a `List<Fruit>`, you're making a `List<Action<Fruit>>`. I'm sorry for the confusion, but to understand my comment you have to ignore the `List` part of your type and focus on the `Action<T>` and `Action<Event>` part. That's where I was trying to draw the analogy.

Comment: @EvgenyVasilyev - Don't forget the `@` notification when responding to a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast `Action<T>` to `Action<Event>` even if `T : Event`, but you can cast any `Action<T>` to `Delegate` and then, at the risk of a run-time error, cast a `Delegate` back to an `Action<T>`. But since the key to the dictionary is `typeof(T)` you can avoid the risk of a run-time error.

Try this code:

```
public class EventBus : ScriptableObject
{
    public Event[] events;

    private Dictionary<Type, List<Delegate>> listeners
        = new Dictionary<Type, List<Delegate>>();

    public void Register<T>(Action<T> function) where T : Event
    {
        listeners[typeof(T)].Add(function);
    }

    public Action<T>[] Retrieve<T>() where T : Event
    {
        return listeners[typeof(T)].Cast<Action<T>>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think what I was trying to do could be accomplished as cleanly as I want. I think I would of had to use Reflection.
What I was trying to accomplish was this:
https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyMessenger/blob/master/src/TinyMessenger/TinyMessenger/TinyMessenger.cs

Comment: @EvgenyVasilyev - That's a lot of code. It's a bit hard to read and digest what's going on without spending a lot of time. One thing that I did notice is that you're using reflection to unsubscribe a `TinyMessageSubscriptionToken` when you call `.Dispose()` on the token. Why not simply pass an `Action` delegate in when you create `TinyMessageSubscriptionToken` to do the unsubscribe? That way there's no reflection and you're tying the unsubscribe to the instance of the `TinyMessengerHub` that created the subscription in the first place.